How to get public access token in Shopee?
I'm trying to fetch the public access token from the docs of Shopee.
Followed the same approach to get the "sign" (right side signature calculation). Link
this "sign" parameter is used in queryParams to get the public access token but in response earlier it was saying "Wrong sign" however now its saying "404 page not found".
Code sample link :  https://open.shopee.com/developer-guide/20
Note : I have code and shopee_id too but when I use to generate sign then in response I'm getting Wrong Sign error.
Link : https://open.shopee.com/documents/v2/v2.public.get_access_token?module=104&type=1
`<?php 


function authShop($partnerId, $partnerKey) {   
    global $host;
    $path = "/api/v2/auth/token/get";
    $redirectUrl = "https://e2xinfotech.com/";

    $timest = time();
    $baseString = sprintf("%s%s%s", $partnerId, $path, $timest);
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $partnerKey);
    $url = sprintf("%s%s?partner_id=%s&timestamp=%s&sign=%s&redirect=%s", $host, $path,             $partnerId, $timest, $sign, $redirectUrl);
    return $url;
}

$host="https://partner.shopeemobile.com";

$partnerId = 20091**;  //hidden due to privacy
$partnerKey = "7051547a446f4879686b716355446c6256504a476d7545567561666646595***";  //hidden due      to privacy

echo authShop($partnerId, $partnerKey);
?>`

